# How create an alias of a Java class or enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum `Color` and I would like to have another one inside a class that has exactly the same items as Color so I'm trying to 'assign' it to a class attribute. Basically I need an alias.

### The not possible way

```
public enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE }

  public class MyClass {
  public static enum Color = Color; // how do I do this in Java?
...
}
```

So My goal would be to call color like this:

```
aColor = MyClass.Color.BLUE;
```

### Correct way in Go

```
type T1 = T2
```

What is the way to do this in Java?

Comment: Why would  you want this, anyway? Why not just use `aColor = Color.BLUE`?

Comment: That looks like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not just use already defined Color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This would be something like a class-local type alias. Java doesn't have anything of the sort.

Comment: Alias is the word I was looking for. Would be great to have it like in Go: https://blog.golang.org/go1.9

Comment: @supercobra It's called a [`typealias` in Swift :)](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59bb136e4e884a5c4f2f5965) Though this isn't something you would use it for, usually

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass {

    public enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE }

}
```

This way you can call:

```
MyClass.Color color = MyClass.Color.BLUE;
```

However `MyClass.Color` != `Color` but they are just enumerations, I do not see any purpose on trying do something like this.

Comment: Go language implemented something like it: "One The most important change to the language (in v9) is the introduction of type aliases: a feature created to support gradual code repair. A type alias declaration has the form: type T1 = T2

...See https://blog.golang.org/go1.9 - Would be great to have this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply define that enumeration as a static field like this:

```
package example;

enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE
}

public class EnumMemberExample {

    public static Color Color;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color blue = EnumMemberExample.Color.BLUE;

        System.out.println(blue.name());
        // => BLUE
        EnumMemberExample instance = new EnumMemberExample();

        System.out.println(instance.Color.GREEN);
        // => GREEN
    }
}
```

This is possible like in this example, eventough I do not prefer using same name for the class type and field. :)

Comment: This does not compile. `public static Color = Color;` => syntax error.

Comment: It depends on your environment. Just change the type or field to something else. Like I said, it is not recomended to use the same names, but I tried to copycat your example. On my setup it did compile. :)

Comment: And one more this. the enum must be in a separate file if it is public. If you try to compile those to from a same file, it will fail.

Comment: This isn't valid java, regardless of environment.

Comment: @VinceEmigh which Java version you using? My example is for 1.8 and up. I edited the example to consist the whole code. Try if this will compile in your environment. 

The example is quite rough and is more like showing that this is possibln eventough I do not prefer to use it directly like this. It is better to have an enumeration in a separete class and if you have have enum type instance of another type like this, it should have be defined like `public static final Color COLOR;` or something to make the code clear.

Comment: @VilleVenäläinen I see it now, but your example would trigger a warning, suggesting you don't call static members from instance members. Rather than introduce nasty work-arounds, you should be encouraging the intended use-case: Since there's no implementation difference between `TypeOne.Color.BLUE` and `TypeTwo.Color.BLUE` when referencing the same `Color` type, there should be no reason to desire this behavior. Even aliasing makes no sense in this case, as the original name is direct. Although since you justify your post, I'll definitely retract the down vote.

Comment: Like I said. I agree with you. :)